# Establish a fixed IP on Windows VM guest on Mac host (VMware Fusion 6)

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have a windows VM running a development web server from visual studio. I can connect to it from my Mac browser at the machine's local IPv4 address. The problem is that every time the host machine sleeps, the guest machine gets a new IP address, which causes mild headaches. Certainly I can work around this by checking the new IP address each time and changing my config files, but there's got to be a better way.

How can I tell the network (or OS, or whatever needs telling) to pick the same address for the windows ethernet0 adapter?

VMware is set up to use NAT ("Share with my Mac") for the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how to connect the VM to  you can edit the dhcpd.conf file to configure VMWare Fusion’s DHCP server to assign specific IP addresses to a VM based on its MAC address.

For that you want to edit `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8`. It contents should resemble the text below:

```
subnet 192.168.87.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 
{
    range 192.168.87.128 192.168.87.254;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.87.255;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.87.2;
    option netbios-name-servers 192.168.87.2;
    option domain-name "localdomain";
    option routers 192.168.87.2;
}
```

For each Vm you want to add an extry like below

```
host vm1 {
    hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:44:57:46;
    fixed-address 192.168.87.101;
}
```

Add one entry for each VM you want to have a static IP.  Make sure that the [virtual] MAC address is correct since this can change when you copy files.